# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main (main Register issue)

Tags: java, android

While Testing my app i got this error. And i am unable to resolve this as i am newbee in Java

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "tableRegister": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

  Process: tweeteve1.loginregister, PID: 3348
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableRegister": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tableRegister(user_id integer primary key autoincrement, Name text, UserName text, Password text, Age int)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1675)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1606)
      at tweeteve1.loginregister.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:28)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
      at tweeteve1.loginregister.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:37)
      at tweeteve1.loginregister.Register$1.onClick(Register.java:37)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Application terminated.
```

my code is here 
Register file:

```
package tweeteve1.loginregister;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.jar.Attributes;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    EditText ePassword;
    EditText eUserName;
    EditText eName;
    EditText eAge;
    Button bRegister;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    eAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    eName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    eUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    ePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btRegister);
    AddData();

    }
    public  void AddData() {
        bRegister.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         boolean isInserted = myDB.insertData(eName.getText().toString(),
                                 eUserName.getText().toString(),
                                 ePassword.getText().toString(),
                                 eAge.getText().toString()
                            );
                        if(isInserted == true)
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
            }
    );
    }
}
```

Do help me please in solving my problem Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is actually self evident - right in the error message - look at your SQL statement that's being executed:

```sql
create tableRegister(user_id integer primary key autoincrement, Name text, UserName text, Password text, Age int)
```

As you can see, there's a space missing between `table` and `Register`.  The stack trace is also very helpfully points out that the error is in line 28 of `DatabaseHelper.java` file:

```
at tweeteve1.loginregister.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:28)
```

So, look at `DatabaseHelper.java` class, line 28, and add the missing space.

**EDIT:** based on the `create table` code from the comment, change it to be:

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TableName + " (user_id integer primary key autoincrement, Name text, UserName text, Password text, Age int)");
```

Note the spaces after `table` and before `(user_id`.

Comment: db.execSQL("create table" + TableName + "(user_id integer primary key autoincrement, Name text, UserName text, Password text, Age int)");
   this is my create table query